# Will installing IPv6/Teredo for bittorrent allow me to connect to more people and vice-versa?

Tags: bittorrent

What's the point of installing IPv6/Teredo for bittorrent?

[image]

(I use Bittorrent btw)

Will it allow me to connect to more people and vice-versa (and hence my downloads would be faster)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may slightly increase performance depending on how many seeds there are. But in my experience it is marginal at best.